# How would you call a contract method that takes Enum type via hardhat?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

In your contract, if you have method that receives an Enum type, how would you pass the arguments from hardhat script?

```
contract SomeContract {

enum WinStatus {
    PENDING,
    LOST,
    WON
}

WinStatus status;

function updateWinStatus(WinStatus _status) public {
   status = _status;
}
}
```

```
// in your hardhat script
...
await someContract.updateWinStatus() // how should i call it. bare in mind hardhat is setup using  javascript not typescript in my case.
```

i tried passing a number, hoping it will get it by order(index). But I am getting 'invalid BigNumber value'. Also, I tried passing a string like "PENDING" or "WinType.PENDING" :thinking:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript natively doesn't support very large numbers (up to the `uint256` type supported in Solidity), so Ethers.js (included in Hardhat) accepts a [BigNumber](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/) instance instead.

```
const myNumber = ethers.BigNumber.from("0") // pass the numeric value as a string
await someContract.updateWinStatus(myNumber) // pass the BigNumber instance
```

Comment: Partially true now that JS support `bigint`

Comment: @RicardoPedroni `BigInt` max value depends on the environment. E.g. 32bit systems have different max value of `BigInt` compared 64bit systems or even to 8bit systems (that might not be able to fit in the whole `uint256` type)... So I can only guess that Ethers.js developers prefer `BigNumber` not because they're not aware of `BigInt` - but rather simply because its functionality is not dependent on the specific environment.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can follow the work-around used by the OpenZeppelin team on their [tests](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/blob/09eeb9a0bdb6ec9a881a97e16b6ddfd44d118e27/test/helpers/enums.js).

Create a new `utils.js` file and add the following method:

```
function Enum(...options) {
  return Object.fromEntries(options.map((key, i) => [key, web3.utils.toBN(i)]));
}
```

After that you'll be able to add any custom enum by using:

```
export const MyCustomEnum = Enum("State1", "State2", "State3");
```

Speaking about your case, the new Enum format defined in the `utils.js` will be:

```
export const WinStatus = Enum("PENDING", "LOST", "WON");
```

Import the new `WinStatus` enum in your script and use it like this:

```
// in your hardhat script
...
await someContract.updateWinStatus(WinStatus.PENDING)
```